# nsstring causing my app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsdictionary

I created dictionary which hold post params.

```
NSDictionary *post_params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager].advertisingIdentifier UUIDString], @"advertisingId",
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"], @"appVersion",
[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion], @"deviceSystemVersion",
[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apnsToken"], @"apnsToken",
[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userId"], @"userId",nil];
```

the above post params are appended to the post request with this code :

```
for (id key in params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[params objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

the above code are executed within `send_post_request` function.

I received this crash report

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x182a982d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132 (NSException.m:162)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1947640e4 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:527)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x182a9f3a4 __methodDescriptionForSelector + 0 (NSObject.m:368)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x182a9c154 ___forwarding___ + 928 (NSForwarding.m:2878)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x18299eccc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92 (NSForwarding.s:772)
5   Foundation                      0x1838cc864 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:] + 180 (NSString.m:1973)
6   Foundation                      0x1838d2e14 +[NSString stringWithString:] + 56 (NSString.m:152)
7   ZVSDV                           0x100084f70 +[ZVSDVutableURLRequest send_post_request:params] + 800 (ZVSDVutableURLRequest.m:79)
```

this report show that the app crash when executing this line of code :

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[params objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

this could be for this reason :

1. `[params objectForKey:key]` return nil value. but this can't happen. because `NSDictionary` can't hold nil value.
2. `[params objectForKey:key]` return integer. I am sure that `NSUserDefaults` return `NSString` object. and the other params objects should be `NSString`.

what could be the problem ?

Comment: `[params objectForKey:key]` will return a nil value if the key isn't in the dictionary

Comment: you fill post_params but you read params - is this relevant?

Comment: at what key does it crash?

Comment: and what is the log of [params objectForKey:key]

Comment: @Daij-Djan thank you for your response.
 1.post_parmas is equal to params.
 2. I don't know at which key it crash. I receive this log from a user which install the app from the app store. 
3.my application work perfect when i test it on my phone. but the problem that some times the app crash on some users phones.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your reply. but iterate through params key using for. so alway i am calling a keys which exist in the dictionary . right ?

Comment: @downvoter: voted to counter -1 vote, please leave a message

Comment: Did the crash report include the exception message?

Comment: @Paulw11I've posted the report log that appear in xcode. where should i view the exception message ?

Comment: that'd be in the conselog and I don't think you have that

Comment: @Daij-Djan if you look at my code. is it possible that params will have  NSNULL object,  [NSNull null] ? if yes then that will cause my app to crash.

Answer (score 2):

one of the objects in `params` in not an NSString.

Run this to check out

```
  for (id key in params) {
    if (![[params objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
      NSLog(@"the object for key '%@' is not a string. It's %@", key, NSStringFromClass([[params objectForKey:key] class]));
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. the app working correctly ,when i test on my phone. but this log i receive from a user who installed the app from the appstore.

Comment: +1 that would indeed be the issue that  results in the given calltree..... but then it should happen for the dev too and not only for some users!?

Comment: how are the values of `userId` and `apnsToken` written to user defaults?

Comment: @Daij-Djan maybe sometimes the system return values that cause crash.
e.g when advertisingId returned or system version or app version.

Comment: do you support older deployment versions

Comment: @Daij-Djan yes ios7 and ios8.

Comment: @vadian using this code [setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"key"]

Comment: and you are sure that deviceToken and userID are doubtless strings?

Comment: @vadian yes , i have test it several times and searched previous versions.

Comment: where do you get deviceToken from

Comment: @Daij-Djan at didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function.

Comment: `didRegister…WithDeviceToken` returns NSData not NSString. This value is supposed to be saved on the webserver rather than on disk

Comment: @vadian yes that's right , but then I convert it to nsstring using this code : NSMutableString *tokenAsString = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                                      initWithCapacity:deviceToken.length * 2];
    char *bytes = malloc(deviceToken.length); [deviceToken getBytes:bytes];
    for (NSUInteger byteCounter = 0; byteCounter < deviceToken.length; byteCounter++){
        char byte = bytes[byteCounter];
        [tokenAsString appendFormat:@"%02hhX", byte];
    }

Comment: if you look at my code. is it possible that params will have NSNULL object, [NSNull null] ? if yes then that will cause my app to crash. right ?

Comment: anything else but `String` will cause the app to crash. Have you registered the appropriate defaults keys during initialization? Don't store the device token in user defaults. The token is retrieved every time the app launches and is supposed to be managed by the web service.

Comment: thank you for your response. 1. How to register default key. what do you mean? , please provide more explanation ? 2. actually i update the nsuserdefaults with device token, every time the user open the app.

Comment: 1. please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html 2. it's useless to store the device token, the device doesn't need it at all. It's a dynamic value to be sent to the web service database to maintain the device for sending the push notifications (e.g. see EasyAPNS for an example)

Comment: aa ok but   1. if i don't initialize , then nil will be returned . and because nsdictionary can't store nil values. so then my app will not crash.        
2.you are right. thank you for your advice